# Converting multi-column json data to java

Tags: java, json

I have web services written in `C#` that perform some basic database access and return a `JSON` string with the information. I need to get this into an array of objects named `Role` (each `Role` representing a row on the database - `RoleId` and `ShortDesc`).

In the web service, the JSON is generated using the Jackson JSON library, like so:

`String output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DataTable);`

This gives me the following output:

```
getJsonTableResponse
{getJsonTableResult=[
{"RoleId":"1de15a5f-0219-4ad9-a5eb-b214238d9cfd","ShortDesc":"description"},
{"RoleId":"f60d8403-9c3c-493b-844c-7ac8ff001b2b","ShortDesc":"description"},
{"RoleId":"b65eecd7-d551-4706-af7a-51d8e4d5093f","ShortDesc":"description"},
{"RoleId":"fbcea65a-5b75-409c-b722-3cb4306c8471","ShortDesc":"description"},
{"RoleId":"fdbc73b2-9fbb-4f3a-a087-3ec41a6800f9","ShortDesc":"description"},
{"RoleId":"360ae291-f8dd-430d-bb1f-ff04bada68c7","ShortDesc":"description"},
{"RoleId":"e363780b-26ae-4580-8b13-22d24fd098d8","ShortDesc":"description"},
{"RoleId":"4b3d37a4-4c8d-42f5-9378-52b0ab6ede30","ShortDesc":"description"}]; 
}
```

Using `java`, how can I convert this `JSON` string to an array of `Role` objects (consiting of `RoleId` and `ShortDesc` string fields)? I'm new to `JSON` and have been struggling to deserialize it so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I guess your json string should be like these:

`{
    "getJsonTableResult": [
        {
            "RoleId": "1de15a5f-0219-4ad9-a5eb-b214238d9cfd",
            "ShortDesc": "description"
        },
        {
            "RoleId": "f60d8403-9c3c-493b-844c-7ac8ff001b2b",
            "ShortDesc": "description"
        },
        {
            "RoleId": "b65eecd7-d551-4706-af7a-51d8e4d5093f",
            "ShortDesc": "description"
        },
        {
            "RoleId": "fbcea65a-5b75-409c-b722-3cb4306c8471",
            "ShortDesc": "description"
        },
        {
            "RoleId": "fdbc73b2-9fbb-4f3a-a087-3ec41a6800f9",
            "ShortDesc": "description"
        },
        {
            "RoleId": "360ae291-f8dd-430d-bb1f-ff04bada68c7",
            "ShortDesc": "description"
        },
        {
            "RoleId": "e363780b-26ae-4580-8b13-22d24fd098d8",
            "ShortDesc": "description"
        },
        {
            "RoleId": "4b3d37a4-4c8d-42f5-9378-52b0ab6ede30",
            "ShortDesc": "description"
        }
    ]
}`

Then, you can use these code to convert JSON string to a list of Role.

> **PS:You should use GSON lib to help you do this job,you can get info about gson [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). add this jar to your project path,and use the code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = readFromFile(new File("json.txt"));
    GObj result = gson.fromJson(json, GObj.class);
    System.out.println(result);
}

static String readFromFile(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        builder.append(scanner.nextLine());
    }
    scanner.close();
    return builder.toString();
}

static class GObj {
    public LinkedList<Role> getJsonTableResult;
    @Override
    public String toString() {return "GObj [getJsonTableResult=" + getJsonTableResult + "]";}
}

static class Role {
    public String RoleId;
    public String ShortDesc;
    @Override
    public String toString() {return "Role [RoleId=" + RoleId + ", ShortDesc=" + ShortDesc + "]";}
}
```

What I read from file is your json string.